# Unable to remove / re-install packages due to php-pear issue

Tags: php, debian-wheezy

Each time I use apt-get related commands to install any package, I get the errors below,

```
 dpkg: error processing php-pear (--configure):
 package php-pear is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php-pear
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can some one advise how to overcome this?
I can reinstall or remove php-pear either, as I get the same error.
Thanks.

Comment: What happens with `dpkg-reconfigure`?

Comment: # dpkg-reconfigure php-pear

/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: php-pear is broken or not fully installed